# MFC , CDataExchange: override the message box alerting the user to the input error

Tags: validation, input, mfc, dialog

I need to validate input of some ctrl in my dialog.
I am using the DDV_.. function to handle the validation,

However, the message box that CDataExchange bringing up alerting the user of the input error , is not what I need (It uses the word "integer" but my users not familiar with this word).

I still wand that the DDV..will handle the validation of the input, but I want to create a custom alert message. How do I do that?

Comment: Care to share the code you've tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the text, you need to write your own DDX- validation routine.

The DDX-Stuff is very simple.
Look into the MFC source code. DDX_Text just calls a static MFC function named _Afx_DDX_TextWithFormat. This function simply calls sscanf and if this fails shows a prompt on error.

Important is just to call pDX->PrepareEditCtrl first. Check if this is a fail or validate call (pDX->m_bSaveAndValidate). And call pDX->Fail on failure.

Just copy the code and write your own private DDX routine.

The source code can be found in your MFC installation here: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\dlgdata.cpp"

Comment: [Technical Note 26](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57weza95.aspx) does a pretty good job at explaining this.